# How to configure WebStorm to debug Polymer

Tags: polymer, webstorm

I want to **debug** my Polymer app in WebStorm, but there is no Polymer specific configuration option. The Node configuration Run is equivalent to `polymer serve` in cmd line, but Debug exits with code 0.

I know I can use Chrome to set breakpoints and inspect my code, but it would be nice to do it in WebStorm.

Here's the output when I click "Debug":

```
/home/user/.node_modules_global/bin/polymer --debug-brk=38501 --expose_debug_as=v8debug serve


   /\˜˜/   /\˜˜/\
  /__\/   /__\/__\    Polymer-CLI
 /\  /   /\  /\  /\
/__\/   /__\/  \/__\  The multi-tool for Polymer projects
\  /\  /\  /   /\  /
 \/__\/__\/   /__\/   Usage: `polymer <command> [options ...]`
  \  /\  /   /\  /
   \/__\/   /__\/


Available Commands

  analyze   Writes analysis metadata in JSON format to standard out       
  build     Builds an application-style project                           
  help      Shows this help message, or help for a specific command       
  init      Initializes a Polymer project                                 
  install   installs Bower dependencies, optionally installing "variants" 
  lint      Identifies potential errors in your code.                     
  serve     Runs the polyserve development server                         
  test      Runs web-component-tester                                     

Global Options

  --env type                      The environment to use to specialize certain  
                                  commands, like build                          
  --entrypoint                    The main HTML file that will be requested for 
                                  all routes.                                   
  --shell string                  The app shell HTML import                     
  --fragment string[]             HTML imports that are loaded on-demand.       
  --root string                   The root directory of your project. Defaults  
                                  to the current working directory.             
  --sources string[]              Glob(s) that match your project source files. 
                                  Defaults to `src/**/*`.                       
  --extra-dependencies string[]   Glob(s) that match any additional             
                                  dependencies not caught by the analyzer to    
                                  include with your build.                      
  -v, --verbose                   turn on debugging output                      
  -h, --help                      print out helpful usage information           
  -q, --quiet                     silence output                                

Run `polymer help <command>` for help with a specific command.


Process finished with exit code 0
```

My html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

    <title>quick-tour</title>
    <meta name="description" content="quick-tour description">

    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">


    <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="/src/quick-tour-app/quick-tour-app.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <quick-tour-app></quick-tour-app>
<img src="https://www.polymer-project.org/images/logos/p-logo-32.png">

  </body>
</html>
```

My custom element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<!--<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/dom-if.html">-->
<!--<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/dom-repeat.html">-->

<dom-module id="quick-tour-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <h1>[[prop1]]!</h1>
  </template>

  <script>
    /** @polymerElement */
    class QuickTourApp extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'quick-tour-app'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          prop1: {
            type: String,
            value: 'Hello'
          }
        };
      }
    }

    customElements.define(QuickTourApp.is, QuickTourApp);
//    window.customElements.define(QuickTourApp.is, QuickTourApp);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

what's the reason for starting Polymer with Node.js debugger? Are you going to debug Polymer cli? Or, you just like to debug your custom component? In the latter case, start the polymer web server in terminal using `polymer serve`, then create a [JavaScript Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.2/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html) run configuration, specifying your component URL there (the one that you normally enter in browser, like `localhost:8080/components/my-el/`) and hit **Debug**.